# glogin.sql supress error when Instance Idle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a pl/sql block in my glogin.sql file to show information from v$instance when I connect on the database server.  Is there a way to suppress the ORA-01034 we would naturally get when the instance is idle?  An idle instance reports that it is idle when you connect, so anything additional is not necessary and could be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use in my login.sql. Tom Kytes book Expert One on One has this script. No sign of ORA-01034 when instance is down. My prompt only shows `idle>`

```
set term off    

-- a lot of stuff

REM here is how I set my signature prompt in sqlplus to 
REM username@database> I use the NEW_VALUE concept to format 
REM a nice prompt string that defaults to IDLE (useful for those
REM of you that use sqlplus to start up their databases - the
REM prompt will default to idle> if your database isn't started)
define gname=idle
column global_name new_value gname
select lower(user) || '@' ||
substr(global_name, 1, decode(dot, 0, length(global_name), dot-1)) global_name
from (select global_name, instr(global_name, '.') dot
from global_name);
set sqlprompt '&gname> '

-- a lot of more stuff    

set term on
```

Comment: I saw that too, but wanted to display the output rather than changing the prompt.  I was able to use it though by selecting the data for the two lines I want to display inside a `set term off`, `set term on` block like Kyte does.  By pre-setting the values to " " before the block the the error isn't displayed if the database is down only a few extra blank lines.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to make it work for a PL/SQL block, so if anyone can add an answer for that I'd +1 it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this shell script to see if a database is open. 
You can probably change it to look for something else.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -x
#
# This script checks to see if a database is open
#
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
echo "Usage: Sid_name"
exit 1
fi
# Set the ORACLE_SID with the first parameter.
# I need to hardcode ${HOME}/scripts because it sets
# the BIN_DIR environment variable
. ${HOME}/scripts/bin/set_oracle_env.sh ${1}

# Log into the DB through SQLPLUS.  You must be the oracle user.
export DBISOPEN=`sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
CONN /as sysdba
SET TERM OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET TRIM ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 130
SET TIMING OFF
SET TERM ON
select status from v\\$instance;
EOF`
if [ "${DBISOPEN}" == OPEN ]; then
echo "TRUE"
else
echo "FALSE"
fi
```

Comment: Are you proposing that this shell script be run from glogin.sql?  If so, how will the script communicate to glogin that the pl/sql block should be run or skipped?

Comment: Sorry I answered a different question. The script above mine looks interesting.